# where can I find binaries of xscreensavers for ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to find out where I can find binaries or Deb xscreensaver packages to download for my ubuntu 12.04 LTS system?

Answer (score 0):

It is avaialble ubuntu [software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xscreensaver/).

You can click → [xscreensaver](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xscreensaver) [image: Install xscreensaver]
to get the app

or in command prompt `sudo apt-get install xscreensaver`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from [Official Launchpad page here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xscreensaver/) and for **Precise Pangolin Source package** [download Binary packages from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/xscreensaver).

Alternately ,try here at [Packages.Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) through Search box, the selecting **Precise** for OS based searching .

Or view through this [Package xscreensaver Searched result](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xscreensaver&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all).